# How to execute existing test case in Setup Script and get value from that responses to the current test case in SOAP UI?

Tags: soapui, load-testing

i have test case (Test case 1) which contains the REST requests i want to run when starting up, so i disable it and calling it via set up script of load test (Test case 2).

However to run load test REST requests i need values from test case 1 responses.
How can i pass the values from one test case to the load UI REST requests?

Response of one REST request in test data (Test case 1)

```
{
   "VotingSessionID": 1326,
   "Name": "Test Vote Session",
   "Questions":    [
            {
         "VotingQuestionID": 4273,
         "Text": "Test A",
         "QuestionNumber": 1,
         "Options":          [
                        {
               "VotingOptionID": 17328,
               "OptionText": "Option A"
            },
                        {
               "VotingOptionID": 17329,
               "OptionText": "Option B"
            },
                        {
               "VotingOptionID": 17330,
               "OptionText": "Option C"
            }
         ],
         "IsActive": false
      }
```

I need to pass the value of "VotingOptionID" to one of REST request in Test case 2.

Answer (score 0):

To run a test step in a Setup Script, you can do like this:

```
def testSuiteName = "yourTestSuiteName"
def testCaseName = "yourTestCaseName"
def testStepName = "yourTestStepName"

def testStep = context.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites[testSuiteName].testCases[testCaseName].testSteps[testStepName]

testStep.run(testRunner, context)
```

To retrieve the value of VotingQuestionID, the easiest way I see is to extract it in your Test Case 1 (which should be called in the Setup Script of Test Case 2).

What you can do then is:

**First**, create a project level property (double click on your Project -> Properties tab at the bottom)

**Second**, add a Script Assertion in the test step of Test Case 1 to retrieve the value of VotingQuestionID when the test step is run. In the Script Assertion, you can add below commands:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
def response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.responseContent)
context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("yourProperty", response.Questions[0].VotingQuestionID)
```

**Third**, use the property in your Test Case 2 using below format

```
${#Project#yourProperty}
```

Comment: Thanks, This works.. instead of setting property in project level i did in test suite level.